# How to document rest parameters in TSDoc

Tags: typescript, tsdoc

is there a way to document with `TSDoc` rest parameters or parameters that going to be destructured inside a function?, a pattern that is used for example in react, where params it be destructured inside the function(Component). Something similar to [this](https://jsdoc.app/tags-param.html#multiple-types-and-repeatable-parameters) in `JSDoc`.

```js
// for now what I am doing is documenting each of the types which are going to compose the `object` param.
export type Props = {
  /** My documentation */
  component?: <sometype>;
  /** My documentation */
  fallback?: <sometype>;
};

export default function MyFun(props: Props): <Type> {
  const { property1, property2, ...rest_of_properties } = props;

  // aditional logic
}
```